# gtsummary package: tbl_svysummary displaying percentage as NA for one variable despite all variables being factors

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm working with the gtsummary package in R, specifically using the tbl_svysummary function to generate weighted descriptive statistics for a survey dataset. However, I'm encountering an issue where the percentage is not displayed for one variable, despite it being a factor variable like the other variables. It is displayed as (NA%)

Here is an example of the code I used where every variable (predictors and outcome) is categorical. The variable **predictor4** does not show the percentage ({p}%), while the {n} and the p-value is displayed. The other predictors work exactly as expected.

```
library(gtsummary)
survey_design %>% 
  tbl_svysummary(
    by = outcome,
    include = c(predictor1, predictor2, predictor3, predictor4),
    statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n}    ({p}%)")
  ) %>%
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**",
    all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**<br>N = {n} ({style_percent(p, digits=1)}%)") %>%
  modify_caption("Weighted descriptive statistics") %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  add_p()
```

I have verified that **predictor4** is a factor variable without missing values or zeroes.

I have already checked the variable type and missing values, updated the package to the latest version, and tried reproducing the problem with a minimal example,

```
tbl_svysummary_weight_test <- tbl_svysummary(survey_design, by = outcome, include = c("predictor4"), statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n_unweighted} ({p})"),
  label = list(predictor4 ~ "Predictor 4")) %>%
  add_p() %>%
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**, N = {n_unweighted}")
```

but the issue persists.

I have included the data here using, `dput(head(survey_design_nomiss_test$variables, 100))`

```
structure(list(outcome = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    predictor1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    predictor2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L), levels = c("No", "Yes"
    ), class = "factor"), predictor3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("No", "Yes"
    ), class = "factor"), predictor4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 
4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 64L, 66L, 
67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 
80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 112L, 113L), class = "data.frame")
```

Could anyone please help me understand why the percentage is not displayed specifically for the **predictor4** variable and suggest any potential solutions or workarounds?

Here is a screenshot of what the issue looks like for a better understanding:

[image: screenshot oftable where the variable shows NA% while other variables show accurate %]

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example (i.e. code with data we can run on our machines). You can find details here on how to prepare your post https://reprex.tidyverse.org/ . When we have an example we can run on our machines, we can then assist.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue in a simplified setting due to the specific nature of the problem.

The issue I'm facing is specific to the 'predictor4' variable when used with the tbl_svysummary function from the gtsummary package. I have checked the variable type and missing values, but the problem does not occur in these scenarios. It seems to be unique to my dataset and the combination of variables used.

Comment: share your data with `dput(yourdata)` or `dput(head(yourdata,100))` if it is too large

Comment: That's a good suggestion Mike. @Amaya if you can somehow create an example we can replicate, happy to investigate further!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution was to change **predictor4** from a factor to a character.

```
mod_data$predictor4 <- factor(data$predictor4, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("No","Yes"))
  
mod_data $predictor4_char <- as.character(mod_data$predictor4)
```

After doing this, I was able to get percentages for the survey summary with predictor4_char. While I was not able to do so using predictor4.

```
library(gtsummary)
survey_design %>% 
  tbl_svysummary(
    by = outcome,
    include = c(predictor1, predictor2, predictor3, predictor4_char),
    statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n}    ({p}%)")
  ) %>%
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**",
    all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**<br>N = {n} ({style_percent(p, digits=1)}%)") %>%
  modify_caption("Weighted descriptive statistics") %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  add_p()
```